# Why background color of gridview cell is not setting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I put this code to set the color of gridview CELL red if not empty. It did but it colored the whole column not a specific cell. Why ?

```
 private void ShowCases()
    {
        short UserID = Convert.ToInt16(Session["UserID"]);

        grdviewCases.DataSource = MngCases.SelectCases(UserID);
        grdviewCases.DataBind();

        foreach (GridViewRow gr in grdviewCases.Rows) 
        {
            if (gr.Cells[14].Text != "")
            {
                gr.Cells[14].BackColor= Color.IndianRed;
            }
        }

    }
```

In short: I want to set background color red if cell is not empty but this code has painted all cells of column# 14, empty and non-empty both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because your "empty" cells actually contain `&nbsp;`.

If you change your code to,

```
 if (gr.Cells[14].Text != "&nbsp;")
 {
     gr.Cells[14].BackColor= Color.IndianRed;
 }
```

it should work:
[image]

Sometimes, using the debugger can be very, very helpful...:O)